# Swift - Detect the user drawing through defined points/areas.

Tags: ios, swift, drawing, collision, point

My app already has the drawing enabled for the user on the screen. How can I **define** certain points in the screen and detect when the user draws through that point? Read about a few swift methods but can't quite grasp if they are applicable for what I need, also I can't find any *"collision"* methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .containspoint method. However I would recommend you to use a rectangle and not a point. It`s very difficult to draw over one certain point. So  you could use CGRect for a rectangle and then again  .containspoint(from the user touched point).